# Remove an object from the memory in Java

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, graph

I created a graph that contains nodes and arcs. When I close the SWING application and manually update the structure of a graph (i.e. remove some nodes and arcs), the old structure of the graph is not deleted from the memory. 
For instance:

```
ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
ArrayList<Arc> arcs = new ArrayList<Arc>();
nodes.add(new Node("N1"));
nodes.add(new Node("N2"));
nodes.add(new Node("N3"));
arcs.add(new Arc("N1","N2"));
arcs.add(new Arc("N2","N3"));
Graph g = new Graph(nodes,arcs);
```

In the Node class I have:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + 
           (isNotConnected() ? " IS NOT CONNECTED" : "" );
}
```

Then I close the application, remove the node "N3" and arc ("N2","N3") and run the application again. It says that `N3 IS NOT CONNECTED`. But I deleted N3!!!
To close the application, I´m using:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Also, I tried to use `g = null`, but it didn´t help as well.

**UPDATE:**

```
public class Node {
    private List<Arc> incoming = new ArrayList<Arc>();
    private List<Arc> outgoing = new ArrayList<Arc>()

    protected Node(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

// ...

    public boolean isNotConnected() {
        return incoming.isEmpty() && outgoing.isEmpty();
    }

    public void addIncoming(Arc arc) {
        this.incoming.add(arc);
    }

    public void addOutgoing(Arc arc) {
        this.outgoing.add(arc);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) How do you remove the node "N3"? 2) Please post the code for `isNotConnected()` 3) What do you mean by "close the SWING application"? Do you restart JVM?

Comment: where exactly does it "say" that? The problem is not with the code fragments you're showing. And it's definitely not possible that objects would persist between application runs.

Comment: I mean that I close the application by exiting the Run mode and returning to the code (I´m using Eclipse).

Comment: What do you mean by removing N3? Do you simply mean deleting the code lines: `nodes.add(new Node("N3"));` and `arcs.add(new Arc("N2","N3"));`, recompiling a new jar file and then running the new jar file?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wonder how does it know that "N3" exists if I deleted this word from the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very unlikely that anything is "*not deleted from the memory*"—each new run is a new JVM, and it means absolutely clean sheet, no history from the previous run.

So I'd rule this possibility out. What's left then?

- You can have a bug in the `isNotConnected()` method — not likely, as I hope you got the `super.toString()` right.
- You can have an older code running. It can be easily diagnosed by changing any string you print, e.g. going from "NOT CONNECTED" to "not connected" — no change in logic, but easy to spot in the logs.
- You can have one more point in the code where you create `N3`
- Etc, etc.

What's important here is that you should never blame the magical non-cleaning memory before you have ruled out all other possibilities.

Have fun!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed a text to ´not connected´, but it still shows NOT CONNECTED during the code execution. I noticed that there is an exclamation mark next to the project icon, although the code does not contain errors. Might it be the reason of this issue? How can I solve it then?

Comment: Well, no magic then :) Let me see... First of all, did you actually save the file? Second, try the "Clean" action — I have no Eclipse at hand, so cannot direct you to the actual dropdown menu, sorry.

Comment: I figured it out. Once I copied a project from another laptop, I had to update build paths of libraries. So, when I did it, the application started working correctly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. You do not detect your problem correctly. Probably you do not compile your code every time and run the old binaries.

Comment: I apply Build All before running the application.

Comment: What is your IDE? How are you running the application? From IDE or outside?

Comment: From IDE. I´m using Eclipse. I tried to close and re-open Eclipse, but the problem remained...It means that something is wrong with my code. But it really does not contain the word "N3". During the execution it writes N3 IS NOT CONNECTED...How could it be??!

Comment: I have sometimes the same effects in eclipse. When changing something in the code it seems to rebuild things but eventually my chage has not been picked up. If I encounter that, I always remove all breakpoints and watches en clean everything. sometimes even close and open project and even close and open eclipse.

Comment: @roel is right. Remove all breakpoints. Make sure you stopped the previous instance of your application. Select your project on package view, then right click and Refresh. Not F5. It sometimes does not work. Use context menu. Then try Project/Clean. Then try to run again. To be sure that your app is changed try to add some print out in the first line of your `main()` and check that it is working.